# Grep pattern within pattern

Tags: regex, bash, grep

```
cat sudo.txt |tr -d "[:blank:]"|grep '=.*[ALLroot].*/usr/bin/vim'
```

I want to track below:

```
=(root)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
```

but not:

```
=(user)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/find
```

Comment: Remove  `=*[ALLroot].*/usr/bin/find|` from the regex.

Comment: I edited the question a bit,,,to make it more clear

Comment: It's not more clear. What exactly do you want to remove and why? Because you want only the entries with `ALL` or `root` inside parentheses?

Comment: Not exactly. Hes grep is searching for one of the letters A, L, r, o, or t, occuring somewhere in front of /usr/bin/vim.

Comment: Then why are you listing `o` & `L` twice? I think you are either failing to be clear on your intent, failing to understand the consequences of your choices, or very possibly both. Apologies if that sounds combative - sincerely - but if you are here to ask questions, don't deflect answers. Provide *specifics* of why they are inapplicable, and/or consider maybe whether the problem is the underlying paradigm of your design. Maybe what you want is more like `grep -E '\bNOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim\b'`

Answer (score 0):

`[ALLroot]` matches `A` or `L` or `r` or `o` or `t`. Use `(ALL|root)` instead

**Given:**

```
cat sudo.txt
=(root)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
=(user)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/find
```

---

```
grep -E '=(\((root|ALL)\))?.*/usr/bin/vim' sudo.txt
=(root)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim
```

**Explanation:**

option `-E` : extended pattern

```
=                   # equal sign
(                   # start group
  \(                # opening parenthesis
    (root|ALL)      # root OR ALL
  \)                # closing parenthesis
)?                  # end group, optional
.*                  # 0 or more any character
/usr/bin/vim        # literally
```

Comment: this gives me more than what i want

Comment: And remove the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 0):

Given the data presented,

```
grep -E '\bNOPASSWD:/usr/bin/vim\b' sudo.txt
```

If that doesn't sufficiently select, please show the examples and explain the missing requirements.